# Use RTKQuery to fetch data in chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have this code, that allow to fetch data from API but the response take long time if I retrieve all data, so to avoid timeout, I need retrieve data in chunks using pagination, this is my code

```
getDataWithDetails: builder.query<Data[], {size?: number; number?: number}>({
        async queryFn(_arg, _queryApi, _extraOptions, fetchWithBQ) {
            const { size, number } = _arg;

            const isFetchingFirstPage = !size && !number;

            const pageSize = size || 20;
            const pageNumber = number || 1;

            let partialResult = await fetchWithBQ({
                url: `data/details/all?page%5Bnumber%5D=${pageNumber}&page%5Bsize%5D=${pageSize}`,
                method: "GET"
            });

            let partialData = partialResult.data as {data:[], meta:[]};

            if (partialData.data.length >= pageSize) {
                const nextPage = pageNumber + 1;
                _queryApi.dispatch({ size: pageSize, number: nextPage });
            }

            return partialData.data
                ? { data: partialData.data as Data[] }
                : { error: partialResult.error as unknown as FetchBaseQueryError }

        },
        providesTags: [{type: "Data", id: "dataList"}]
    })
```

But for unknown reason the dispatch is not working, can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is there any error or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple queries on each page as shown [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1163#discussioncomment-849158) or append your data to an existing cache with the help of the entity adaptor as shown [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1163#discussioncomment-2477006). I haven't tested your approach but it looks like it will cache each page separately. Loading data in chunks isn't straight forward with rtk query so you can pick any approach that works for you from this discussion: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1163